# Is there a way to make a one time use command/action in a windows command line? eg. Inputting a license key

Tags: windows, validation, batch-file, user-input

The problem is basically in the title above. How do I for example enable a one time action example inputting a license key.

```
set /p key= "Please input your license key: "
IF [%key%]= [something] goto :start
IF [%key%]= [anything] goto :start
```

Is there a way to only make the code above pop up only the first time using it? and if they entered the wrong key it will just stay like that until they enter the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common method would be to use a simple `GoTo` loop:

```sh
:GetKey
ClS
Set /P "key=Please input your license key: "
Set "key=%key:"=%"
(Set key) 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LX "key=CoRrEcT KeY" >NUL || GoTo GetKey

:Start
Echo You entered the correct license key [%key%].
Pause
```